# Insert string containing single quote using sed

Tags: bash, sed

I have a network script where i'm trying to insert a line after one containing the string default route. I've used

```
sed -i '/default route/a option device '/dev/modem'' /etc/network
```

But it is not including the single quotes ie it returns

```
option device /dev/modem
```

and i need it to read

```
option device 'dev/modem'
```

Comment: Use: `sed -i "/default route/a option device '/dev/modem'" file`

Comment: You may want to read https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Quoting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The primary issue is that you're reusing single quotes. The simplest approach is to wrap the command in double quotes:

```
sed -i.bak "/default route/a\
option device '/dev/modem'" /etc/network
```

I've also made a couple of other changes, to make the command more compatible across different versions of sed:

1. I've moved the string to be appended onto a new line and used `a\`.
2. I've added a suffix to the `-i` switch (`-i` isn't standard but at least with a suffix it's *more* standard).